# Is there a reason Commands are Slower than normal Requests?

Tags: symfony

I am currently refactoring some code to transform some actions in commands in my Symfony 2.7 application.

At first, I was making a GET request to some endpoint, the corresponding controller was making a call to a service and responded with a 200 http response.

Now, I want to execute this service from a command interface so I use the [Console Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html) of Symfony.

The problem is: The command way is very, very slow. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Are you running the commands with the production environment and debug mode off?

Comment: Not at all, I didn't know that there was a dev/prod environment for commands, how can I check that? (for web, I am using `app.php` and `app_dev.php`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Commands, by default, are run in dev environment, meaning more logging, capturing data for the profiler...

Try appending `--env=prod`.

Comment: Combining with `--no-debug` seems to be useful as well

Comment: Indeed, you should combine `--env=prod` with `--no-debug`. You can also use environment variables for that, for example with the `export` command: SYMFONY_ENV=prod and SYMFONY_DEBUG=0.